# Hide gridLines in Kendo UI Chart Angular 2

Tags: angular, kendo-chart, kendo-ui-angular2

I am using Kendo UI Chart with Angular 2,
with the Chart by default grid lines are coming, but I want to hide it. I got the class from API which is "[GridLines](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/charts/api/GridLines/)". but where to use it that I am not getting. and also I want to hide my X-Axis.

Coming Result:
[image: comingResult]

Expected Result:

[image: expectedResult]

Code:

```
<kendo-chart>
    <kendo-chart-value-axis>
        <kendo-chart-value-axis-item [title]="{ text: 'Score' }" [min]="0" [max]="11" >
        </kendo-chart-value-axis-item>
    </kendo-chart-value-axis>

    <kendo-chart-series-defaults type="bar">
        <kendo-chart-series-defaults-labels format="">
        </kendo-chart-series-defaults-labels>
    </kendo-chart-series-defaults>

    <kendo-chart-category-axis>
        <kendo-chart-category-axis-item  [categories]="chartObject.skills">
        </kendo-chart-category-axis-item>
    </kendo-chart-category-axis>

    <kendo-chart-series>
        <kendo-chart-series-item color="#337ab7" [data]="chartObject.rates" type="bar" [border]="{ width: 0 }">
        </kendo-chart-series-item>
    </kendo-chart-series>
</kendo-chart>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I hide grid lines like below:

```
<kendo-chart-axis-defaults [majorGridLines]="{ visible : false}">
</kendo-chart-axis-defaults>
```

To remove chart X-Axis :

```
<kendo-chart-value-axis>
    <kendo-chart-value-axis-item [line]="{visible:false}" labels="false">
    </kendo-chart-value-axis-item>
</kendo-chart-value-axis>
```

Comment: @alexGyoshev, Thanks for proper indentation. :)

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this by making changing property of a css class like following

```
.k-var--chart-major-lines {
    background-color:white;
}
```

Comment: Yes, indeed, we can achieve it but I wanted to know the Kendo UI approach. thanks for your Help. :)

Comment: While this will set the grid lines color, it is a better idea to use the provided SASS variables and compile the theme. This way, you can set `$chart-major-lines: #fff;` to modify the theme, instead of overriding it via CSS.

Comment: Yes now iam using SASS variables instead of overriding thanks for your help